# How to selectively export oracle to dump - minus some procedures or packages

Tags: oracle, select, export, package, procedures

We need to export an 11g database to get it into an 10g system. But we need to leave out a package, or at least some functions and procedures, that were accidentally implemented using 11g-only features.

Thankfully, the 10g is just a reporting database and we need only a few of the procedures that were implemented in 10g.

Any thoughts? I've seen some options for table-only exports, or selectively exporting certain tables. But we do need some of the procedures to come along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using expdp ([data pump export](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm)) on the 11g database specifying the VERSION and INCLUDE parameters:

```
expdp dumpfile=10g.dmp directory=data_pump_dir version=10.2 INCLUDE=PROCEDURE:"LIKE '%XXX'"
```

This will produce a data pump export file that is compatible with the 10g version of data pump import and includes procedures ending in XXX.

Alternatively, you can use the EXCLUDE parameter instead of include to if you have just a few objects to exclude.

If you use INCLUDE, only those items you specify will be exported.

There are a lot of options for [filtering objects](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#i1009903) using data pump export/import via the INCLUDE/EXCLUDE parameters.

Comment: Nice. We have been sending dump files (as opposed to pump) files to the recipient for the past few years. Are these same options available under exp for a dump versus pump?

Comment: Not that I know of. Data Pump is a newer product with lots more options and capabilities.